# How to pass response to server in json format?

Tags: android, json

I am new to json.

I want to pass response to server through json and read result.

I want to pass data like as fallows to the given url

{"dataset":
[{"fname":"fane",
"Lname":"lname"
}
]}

if any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you wrote already is correct JSON. Are you looking for how to make a POST request? How to construct JSON programmatically? What?

Comment: i want to pass info through post like the above format

Comment: can you explain it bit more?

Comment: i want to send data like {"dataset":[{"fane":"fname","lname":"lname"}]" this format.i don't know how to send like the above format to json service.

Comment: This post must help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android